# How to push an object into an array nested in an array of objects?

Tags: javascript

So I have this arr

```
let arr = [{
 category_set_id: 25,
 name: "25name",
 el: [
   {name: "25name1", value: "25value1"}
 ]
},
{
 category_set_id: 44,
 name: "44name",
 el: [
   {name: "44name1", value: "44value1"}
 ]
},
]
```

And this is the element i need to push into this arr of objects

```
let elToPush = {category_set_id: 44, name: "44name2", value: "44value2"}
```

As you can see, it belongs in the second eleement of the arr, and it must somehow be pushed into the el property, resulting in

```
let arr = [{
 category_set_id: 25,
 name: "25name",
 el: [
   {name: "25name1", value: "25value1"}
 ]
},
{
 category_set_id: 44,
 name: "44name",
 el: [
   {name: "44name1", value: "44value1"},
   {name: "44name2", value: "44value2"}
 ]
},
]
```

So I know I can maybe first filter the arr to get my desired section, fe

```
let toModify = arr.filter(i => i.category_set_id === elToPush.id)
```

Then having that I could

```
let newarr = [toModify.el, ...elToPush]
toModify.el = newarr
```

And finally I must somehow replace it in the global arr

Can someone lend a hand with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `findIndex` to find the index of `category_set_id: 44,` from `arr`. If `arr` contains such object then it will return the index which will be greater than `-1`. Then use this index to push the required value

```js
let arr = [{
    category_set_id: 25,
    name: "25name",
    el: [{
      name: "25name1",
      value: "25value1"
    }]
  },
  {
    category_set_id: 44,
    name: "44name",
    el: [{
      name: "44name1",
      value: "44value1"
    }]
  }
];

let elToPush = {
  category_set_id: 44,
  name: "44name2",
  value: "44value2"
};

const getIndex = arr.findIndex(item => item.category_set_id === elToPush.category_set_id);
if (getIndex > -1) {

  arr[getIndex].el.push({
    name: "44name2",
    value: "44value2"
  })

};

console.log(arr)
```

Alternatively you can also use `find` which will return the object if `category_set_id` matches

```js
let arr = [{
    category_set_id: 25,
    name: "25name",
    el: [{
      name: "25name1",
      value: "25value1"
    }]
  },
  {
    category_set_id: 44,
    name: "44name",
    el: [{
      name: "44name1",
      value: "44value1"
    }]
  }
];

let elToPush = {
  category_set_id: 44,
  name: "44name2",
  value: "44value2"
};

const obj = arr.find(item => item.category_set_id === elToPush.category_set_id);
obj && obj.el.push({
  name: elToPush.name,
  value: elToPush.value
})
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

so first we want to find the right object to insert our new element in, and then mutate the internal array with the right fields

```
updateArray(newObject) {
  const elemToChange = arr.find(object => object.category_set_id == newObject.category_set_id)
  const objectToPush = { name: newObject.name, value: newObject.value }
  elemToChange.el.push(objectToPush)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use find for having a reference to the searched object, and then you can insert (push to) the element in the el array of the found object.

```js
let arr = [{
    category_set_id: 25,
    name: "25name",
    el: [{
      name: "25name1",
      value: "25value1"
    }]
  },
  {
    category_set_id: 44,
    name: "44name",
    el: [{
      name: "44name1",
      value: "44value1"
    }]
  }
];

let elToPush = {
  category_set_id: 44,
  name: "44name2",
  value: "44value2"
};

const obj = arr.find(item => item.category_set_id === elToPush.category_set_id);
if (obj) {

  obj.el.push({
    name: "44name2",
    value: "44value2"
  })

};

console.log(arr)
```